# How to reload a custom lightning component within a lightning page?

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning, javascript

I have created a lightning component for a lightning page.
After the final save method, I am able to refresh another related list in the lightning page using 'e.force:refreshView' but I am not able to find any way to reload my custom lightning component?
Is there any standard way of doing that?
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Add a handler in your Lightning component for the event force:refreshView and then call you init method as an action on this handler.

```
<aura:handler event="force:refreshView" action="{!c.doInit}" />
```

Hope this will help.

Comment: But this will just execute the init method and won't reset the value of attributes, won't reload the DOM.

Comment: @TejenderMohan
As there is no standard way to refresh a component. Here you can create a function named refresh, and reinitialize all the attribute in the function. Call this function from the above handler instead of **doInit** 
Something like --
_<aura:handler event="force:refreshView" action="{!c.refresh}" />_

Comment: Hey Avinash
Thanks (y)
Can you please share a way to reinitialize object list type attribute?

Comment: Just initialize with empty quotes, that will work..

**Example :**

`<aura:attribute name="msg" type="String"/> 
<aura:attribute name="ContactList" type="List"/>`

**reinitialize these by ...**

`component.set("v.msg","");
component.set("v.ContactList","");`